# Should ratio definition have these words, of the same kind?

Tags: ratio

This is the ***definition of ratio*** that is on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio).

> “a ratio is a relationship between two numbers *of the same kind*”

Considering the ratio of a moving distance to the fuel amount in a vehicle, I think it would be better if the definition were this: “a ratio is a relationship between two numbers”, without the last part. Should there be the words, *of the same kind*, in there?

Comment: Well, what would you consider $\frac{5}{\aleph_1}$ to be?

Comment: @Arkamis, If the denominator is indefinite character instead of number, we can’t find out for every amount of one thing how much there is of another thing. So do you mean that the words, ‘of the same kind’, denotes same kind of number? I mean if the numbers are natural number - same kind, for example, isn’t it matter what their units are: in OP, one is kilometre, the other litre.

Comment: $\aleph_1$ is a [transfinite number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transfinite_number).